# Google App Engine query on MySQL in same project with Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, servlets

I have a SQL instance "MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7" which must process a simple update query operation from a Google App Engine.

This Google App Engine Standard Java Project  service has been created with
JDK 1.8,
Eclipse Oxygen,
Hibernate 3,
and classic servlet stuff included.

Whenever I run the project from my computer, the connection will work properly and the program will execute without errors. But when I deploy it into Google creating a new Version, if I try it, the query page will load for 30secs until error 500 appear. 
Details of the error:

Display of website:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

Display of stack trace:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at hbt.HibernateUtil.
>   (HibernateUtil.java:21) at dao.TurnoDAO.getTurno (TurnoDAO.java:69) at
>   controlador.Main.getTurno (Main.java:32) at RegularizarTurno.doPost
>   (RegularizarTurno.java:33) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
>   (HttpServlet.java:637) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
>   (HttpServlet.java:717)

The problem is that the SessionFactory won't create, because the project is unable to connect to the database, oposed as in my computer.
So, as in Google documents say, if the services run in the same GoogleProject there won't be accessing problems, the answer shouldn't go the permissions way.

package hbt;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import entities.*;

```
public class HibernateUtil{
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    try {
        AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Turno.class); 
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Persona.class);        


        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();

   }catch (Throwable ex){
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); //LINE 21
    }
}  
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

So, IP addressing works fine, permissions should be OK, everything related to coding is fine (because tested in 2 PCs). What am I missing? Are there any special permissions I should adquire? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you change the database configuration? Does it try to connect to your local database from google?

Comment: @Konrad Hello, yes, it connects perfectly from localhost (that's the weird thing). What do you mean by the db config, the hibernate.config file? As soon as the project worked in localhost, I deployed it to the GAE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**: There was a weird permission problem where the GAE was not allowed to access a database with the same project-id. It was solved by allowing all networks to access to the database. Altough risky, we still need an user with password to enter. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you're using Cloud SQL and JDBC driver `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver` then I believe that will take care of permissions, and you shouldn't need to open up your database to all networks.

Comment: @crazystick Indeed, that was the weird part. Until I let access to all the networks, the connection wouldn't work.

Comment: and you're definitely using `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver` and not `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` ? You need different connection strings for production environment too, e.g. `jdbc:google:mysql://<proj-id>:<region>:<instance>/<db_name>?user=root` too.

Comment: @crazystick damn, I wasn't up to that! I just used the same jars and commands I use for regular. Where can I get proper documentation? Thank you very much!

Comment: I will try as soon as possible to check it out and edit the "answer".